# Adding CSS file in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I am new in React development. I am trying to add a CSS file in my App. My file tree is like below

[image]

My `App.js` file is like below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from '../pages/Home';
import Login from '../pages/Login';
import Register from '../pages/Register';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="container">
          <Switch>
            <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
            <Route path='/login' exact component={Login} />
            <Route path='/register' exact component={Register} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I am trying to browse below URL

```
http://localhost:3000/register
```

But I can see only HTML, no CSS there.

Comment: Please add the code you have in app.css

Comment: Are you using Webpack? If you are please share your `webpack.config.js`.

Comment: @EdgarHenriquez, How to use `Webpack` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can't just import it an leave it there, it needs to be loaded in the head of your document

```
<head>
<link rel='preload' href={CSS_URL} as='style' />
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the css at the end of all import

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from '../pages/Home';
import Login from '../pages/Login';
import Register from '../pages/Register';

import './App.css';
```